# Microsoft Graph - Authorization for applicable users

Tags: c#, server, blazor, token

I have a site that allows both members of Azure AD and public-non-account users access it;

To do this I disabled the default/fallback policty in `builder.Services.AddAuthorization`

However, the downside is that every time an error is generated in IIS/Console

`Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition: Error: False MSAL 4.57.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.11 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-11-07 16:08:08Z] Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException , ErrorCode: user_null HTTP StatusCode 0 CorrelationId at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

I do want to keep the microsoft graph in place for the times I need it for logged in users.

What's the best way to handle the above error as to not generate errors every time?